# Patching WSO2 BPS - Carbon

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

I am attempting to patch the carbon app within our WSO2 BPS 3.2.0 environment. We are currently runnning 4.2.0 patch0005 which was bundled with BPS. There is a fix in patch0007 that resolves a bug we are experiencing. Does anyone have a working processes including the steps to download the patch source?

I see there is a service pack listed here... https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/service-packs/, but this does not include the jar files needed for the service pack.

I'd appreciate a point in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can build and apply the patch0007:

Pre-requisites:

- Java 1.6  (it won't build with 1.7 or later versions)
- Maven 3.0.5  (may have problems with later versions so try to install this version)

How to build:

- Checkout Kernel 4.2.0 (https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/)
- Build the kernel (mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true) - this step is optional and you may proceed to the next step without this, but if you face any problems, then start from this step. This will take some time.
- Goto patches directory
- Build each patch from 0001 to 0007 in that order (it's important to perform this in order without missing any)
- Now you have built all patches upto 7, now you have to apply both patch0006 and patch0007 to the BPS (it already has upto patch0005)
- Those patches are in patch0006/distribution/target/WSO2-CARBON-PATCH-4.2.0-0006.zip and a similar location for patch0007
- unzip those files and take patch0006 and patch0007 directories from them and copy to `<BPS>/repository/components/patches`
- restart the server

Answer (score 1):

it's there in the [README.txt](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/service-packs/servicepack001/README.txt) file!

### INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS

(i)   Shutdown the server, if you have already started.

(ii)  Copy the wso2carbon-version.txt file to /bin.

(iii) Copy the servicepack001 to  (_BPS_HOME_)/repository/components/patches/

(iv)  Restart the server with :

- Linux/Unix :  sh wso2server.sh
- Windows    :  wso2server.bat

**Note: This is not a patch, it's a service pack. all the wso2 patches and SPs comes with a README.txt file which include how to apply the correction.**

Comment: Yes. I did follow the README files instructions and copied the wso2carbon-version.txt file into bin and moved the service pack into the patches folder. Permissions were all good, but this fails with the error .....    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wso2bps-3.2.0/repository/components/patches/servicepack001/distribution (Is a directory)

Comment: Hi @BTD I think rajeev has provided the answer! :)