# Error during Build from Source WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to make some changes in WSO2 Identity Server v5.0.0 through using following tools;

1. Eclipse (kepler)
2. Subversive (for svn)
3. JDK 1.7
4. Maven 3.2.3
5. Windows 7

I have done following
1. svn checkout (/svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk11/) 
2. then choose the is5.0.0 from the "products20494/is204941" 
3. right click on pom.xml file
4. Run as maven clean (result show success with following warning)

```
 "SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

     [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [WARNING] .............................
    ......................

        [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.wso2.identity:org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager:bundle:1.0
        [WARNING] The expression ${pom.artifactId} is deprecated. Please use ${project.artifactId} instead.
        [WARNING] The expression ${pom.artifactId} is deprecated. Please use ${project.artifactId} instead.
        [WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.utils:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.wso2.carbon.utils-4.0.0.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 78, column 25

    --------------------
    ------------
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2.043s
    [INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 12 10:14:57 PKT 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 12M/113M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### **But when I Run as maven install it show following errors;**

---

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.5:bundle (default-bundle) on project org.wso2.identity.styles: Error calculating classpath for project MavenProject: org.wso2.identity:org.wso2.identity.styles:5.0.0 @ D:\wso2is\5.0.0\modules\styles\product\pom.xml: The JAR/ZIP file (C:\Users\Rizvi\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\ssl\not-yet-commons-ssl\0.3.9\not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.9.jar) seems corrupted, error: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 11] cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.wso2.identity.styles

-------------------
-------------------
```

anyone can help me in this regard ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need the following in order to successfully build carbon 4.2 or older versions:

- Java 1.6 (it won't build with 1.7 or later versions)
- Maven 3.0.5 (may have problems with later versions so try to install this version)

Then, when we look at the [release matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/), we see that there are 8 kernel patches released by the time chunk 11 was released. You have to build all those kernel patches one by one in the order from patch0001 to patch0008 before building the chunk 11. Patch sources are [available here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/).

Then, checkout the carbon platform Turing version which is [available here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/) and build `product-releases/chunk-11` which will build the IS 5.0.0 pack.

Comment: Whether I checkout whole link (//svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk11/) or select Identity server product from chunk11 tree ... as I am newbie...Plz tell me ....How can I build patches in Eclipse...Further, can you tell me step by step build from source instructions for Identity Server v5.0.0

Comment: Furthermore, i have checkout WSO2 Carbon from (//svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/), now what next to do with this carbon (clean, update, install or otherwise !). I am sorry to put this type of question, as I said I am newbie... plz ignore little awarness about building from source code (its my first time experience !!!!)

Comment: go to the patches directory in the kernel and run 'mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true' in command prompt for all the patches from patch0001 to patch0008. Then build the platform chunk-11 with the same command.

Comment: You may find this answer useful for building the kernel patches (not the same question though)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253739/patching-wso2-bps-carbon/27262358#27262358

Comment: Also if you just want to change a component in IS, there's no need to build the whole IS product. just do the modification and build the relevant component (not entire chunk). Then apply that built jar file to IS as a patch.

Comment: Thanks for your precious guidance ! Now I have build patches and also chucnk-11 (only IS, other module I have comments out)....However, the next step to edit the source code in eclipse is not working by trying to import the source code as a Maven project ! Can plz help me further !

Comment: What is the exact problem you faced when opening with eclipse? Try opening only the component you want to modify instead of the whole component tree... it will be easier.

Comment: incremental-build-plugin:1.3 incremental-build (10 errors)

Comment: can you tell me that what are the components of WSO2 Identity Server v5.0.0 (name them plz)... ?